# Developer VMs on the domain

Tags: development, virtual-machine, domain

My organization recently hired 2 SharePoint developers, myself and another person. Prior to this, the organization has never had any developers, so we are in the process of setting of the infrastructure needed to do SharePoint dev.

One issue being discussed is around putting developer VMs on the domain. Our domain admins would prefer we put them on the test domain, for isolation. However, our TFS server is on the production domain. There is currently no trust between the domains at all, so the developers have suggested that a one way trust be setup between test and prod (test trusts prod). That would allow us to keep TFS on the production domain, and still access it from our VMs, and our workststions.

This is similar to how I have seen it done in other organizations, but are there any problems with this approach? Is there a better way?

Comment: never used TFS, but isn't it supposed to ask credentials if there is no trust relationship, as any windows authenticated app would do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Steve B said, there's no problem having TFS on another domain. It will prompt you for credentials.

We typically develop on SharePoint VMs that are also their own domains - thus they are completely independent. We have no problem with using TFS on our company domain, though it does help if you use Windows's option to remember your credentials. See Credential Manager for details.

Otherwise, I just get prompted, fill in my login details, and presto! It works.

Comment: I guess I was (mistakenly) assuming that we wouldn't be able to access TFS unless there was a trust. Thanks for setting me straight!